# Making html sections visible when the screen is too bright

Tags: html, css

I have a page that i am trying to view on 23" and 24" inch screens but i have a problem. Sometimes the screens are too bright and since my page has subtle borders, the sections of the page are not well separated since a user cant see because the screen is too bright.

I checked on which browsers luminosity is supported https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mixblendmode&search=luminosity but that didn't yield much.

This didn't work either

```
@media screen and (luminosity: bright) {
  body {background-color: #ddd; color: #111;}
}
```

Can i detect when a screen is too bright using css alone?. I haven't come across a javascript solution either.

Comment: Luminosity seems to have been renamed to light-level and punted to the [level 5 draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries-5/). From what I can tell it's an indicator of ambient light level, not screen brightness, so it might not suit your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what I'm seeing here :
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/@media/light-level
It's not supported by any browsers, I was not able to find documentation about a luminosity attribute in Media Queries.

According to that:
https://medium.com/dawsonandrews/responding-to-environmental-light-levels-with-css-media-queries-level-5-f3e0beb78c88
It's seems that this feature is getting informations from the light sensor of the mobile, which makes sense.

I don't think a web browser can get any pertinents informations about screen brightness...
It's not something absolute, even if you had the possibilité of getting the value in percentage on the brightness of the screen, it doesn't give you an absolute value that can be used efficiently.

My advice on your UI problem : you should think about putting more contrast between the colors of your border and your background.